# "Duplicar" ou "Duplicata" na aba da UI (fila de análise)?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Eu estava verificando a fila de análise de "Votos para Fechar", e me deparei com uma questão que havia sido entendida como duplicata por algum usuário. Ao procurar uma forma de ver a "original", notei a grafia da aba na UI:

<kbd>[image: Captura de tela mostrando o erro]</kbd>

Creio que o detalhe marcado em vermelho deva ser grafado como "Duplicata".

Aproveitando, talvez fosse o caso de usar "duplicata" nas duas ocorrências de "duplicado" que também aparecem na mesma captura.